# Macro for inserting arguments into enumerate

Tags: macros

I have so many

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),topsep=1pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
    blah blah
\end{enumerate}
```

in my document and I'm tired of pasting `[label=(\arabic*),topsep=1pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]` over and over. Is there a way that I can make a macro to do this for me? I tried

```
\def\enumargs{topsep=1pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),\enumargs]
    blah blah
\end{enumerate}
```

but I keep getting the error "Package enumitem Error: topsep=1pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=* undefined." Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: you should hardly ever need the optional argument on a list, only if that list is different from the defaults set up for the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation. You have to use in the preamble, for lists  at the first level, just this:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\arabic*),topsep=1pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
```